# Ruby on Rails: Polymorphic Association with Nested Attributes, fields not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes, polymorphic-associations

I have a polymorphic association form and I'd like to build a nested form, but the fields are not showing up:

**views/reviews/_form.html.erb**:

```
<%= form_for [@reviewable, @review] do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :review_images do |i| %>
    <%= i.file_field :image %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**review.rb**:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :review_styles_attributes
  belongs_to :reviewable, polymorphic: true
  has_many :review_styles
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :review_images, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**review_image.rb**:

```
class ReviewStyle < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :review_id, :image 
  belongs_to :reviewable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :review
end
```

**reviews_controller.rb**:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_reviewable

  def new
    @review = @reviewable.reviews.new
    @review_style = @review.build_review_style
    3.times {@review.review_styles.new}
  end

  def edit
    # not sure what goes here if I need to edit as well
  end

  private
  def get_reviewable
    @reviewable = params[:reviewable].classify.constantize.find(reviewable_id)
  end

  def reviewable_id
    params[(params[:reviewable].singularize + "_id").to_sym]
  end
end
```

Comment: does `<% emd %>` is the typo in question , or is it the `answer` .

Comment: @ParitoshPiplewar its a typo, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:

```
  <%= f.fields_for :review_images do |i| %>
    <%= i.file_field :image %>
  <% end %>
```

From looking at your code, it should be:

```
  #app/views/reviews/new.html.erb
  <%= f.fields_for :review_styles do |i| %>
    <%= i.file_field :image %>
  <% end %>

  #app/controllers/reviews_controller.rb
  def new
      @review = @reviewable.reviews.new
      @review.review_styles.build
  end
```

You should note when you're building associative values, you should use `.build` for plural / multiple associations, and `build_` for singular

Comment: dang, i thought that would be the case... but it still doesn't show up in my view